# First Time Using Gulp - Where are my files being saved?

Tags: html, optimization, compression, minify, gulp

Im trying to use Gulp for the first time, ive followed a number of tutorials and able to run Gulp, however i cannot find where my newly created files have been placed!

Here is my project structure:

```
GulpTest
  Authenticated
     Images
     Javascript

  NotAuthenticated
     Images
     Javascript
```

Quite a simple setup.

Within my root folder (GulpTest), i have a:

package.json file with:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "^3.5.2",
  "gulp-rename": "^1.1.0",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.1.7",
  "gulp-uglify": "^0.2.1",
  "gulp-jshint": "^1.5.0"
 }
}
```

A a gulpfile.js file with:

```
    // Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// Include Our Plugins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
//var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

var paths = {
  scripts: ['Authenticated/javascript*.js', 'NotAuthenticated/javascript*.js'],
};


// Lint Task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('Authenticated/*.js')
    //return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

// Compile Our Sass
//gulp.task('sass', function() {
//    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
//        .pipe(sass())
//        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
//});


gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  // Minify and copy all JavaScript (except vendor scripts)
  return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('Authenticated/js'));
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('Authenticated/*.js', ['lint', 'scripts']);
    //gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['lint', 'scripts']);
    //gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

// Default Task
//gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'sass', 'scripts', 'watch']);
gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

I've created a new folder within Authenticated called js, i thought the new code would/is created here??

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your js files have names like `javascript1.js` they are minified and saved in the 'Authenticated/js' directory.

When you say

```
gulp.src(paths.scripts)
```

this will match all the files in the current working directory, that match the rules you passed to the src() function.
In this case you passed

```
['Authenticated/javascript*.js', 'NotAuthenticated/javascript*.js']
```

so it will search for files in the two folders that begin with 'javascript' and end with '.js'.
For example 'javascript_Something.js'

If you wanted to include any file that has the '.js' extension, just say

```
var paths = {
  scripts: ['NotAuthenticated/*.js','Authenticated/*.js']
};
```

See the documentation for [gulp.src()](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options) and for [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).

Comment: your post helped to identify the issue. My .js files are not in 'Authenticated/javascript*.js'.... They are in 'Authenticated/javascript/*.js'... This has no minified it as expected.